# Migrate from sqlite to postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlite, migration, migrate

I have sqlite database with alot of data.
I want to "copy" (migrte) all the data from my sqlite to postgres data base.
Any one know about a tool that help with migrate sqlite to postgres?
I google it but didnt find something.
Thanks alot for helping.

Comment: what did you search? just google: "convert database tool"

Comment: i tried migrate sqlite to postgres.

Comment: search convert database tool. it show you many of them. most of db converters support both sqlite and postgres as they are popular these days. good luck!

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was to run sequel from ruby. Just run the commands:

```
gem install sequel
```

You will need to have installed on your system the **devel packages for postgres , sqlite and ruby**

Run the command:

```
gem install pg sqlite3
```

Create an empty database on postgresql, let's say testDB and assign a grant permission to a user

From the command prompt run:

```
sequel -C sqlite:///path/to/sqlitedb.db postgres://user:password@host/testDB
```

This will run with no errors.

Comment: what should the path format be like...isnt it sqlite:///home/username/project/db.sqlite3

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using fullcopyconvert, it does the suggested migration.